# Duplicate image is created using Vue and laravel

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5, vuejs2

Hello guys I'm new to Vue so I want to know why duplicate image is created for eg:- when I m using inline css after compiling it create one more image in public folder. Note I have image/logo.png in resource/assets/js folder
 example code

```
<template>
<Img src="image/logo.png">
</template>
```

This example code is located in resource/assets/js . thing is that during compiling image file should be present in resource/assets/js/image/logo.png otherwise it throw error module not present.is there any another alternative for this, eg:- image file present in one common folder so it does not create duplicate image and npm run watch does not throw error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to default webpack config of laravel.

> By default, Laravel Mix and Webpack will find example.png, copy it to your public/images folder, and then rewrite the url() within your generated stylesheet.

Detail [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mix#url-processing)

Comment: is there any way so i can pass dynamic url

Comment: I don't think you can. Since webpack need to know the path to do work correctly. you can't do `var urlpath = 'images.png';` and `<Img src="urlpath">` as webpack can't resolve it.